# Browser can load the page, but the ping is failed

Tags: networking, browser, hosting

When i use my chrome to open https://340bopais.hrsa.gov/ it works well, but when i try to ping it gives me:

```
ping 340bopais.hrsa.gov

Pinging 340bopais.hrsa.gov [165.112.137.204] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 165.112.137.204:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),
```

So, why is that? why the pings are not successful?

Comment: I guess ICMP isn't provided by the provider

Answer (score 0):

PING (the Packet Internet Groper) is an ICMP (Internet Control Management Protocol) protocol.

HTTPS is a Transport protocol.

Many network providers and service managers restrict access to their resources for only the necessary protocols and ports.

It is quite likely that the organisation that hosts 340bopais.hrsa.gov has configured firewalls and other network infrastructure to only permit TCP traffic on port 80 and 443 to their server.

Comment: @Kamyar Parastesh

Did this answer help you?